# Detect page events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a template bought on a portal and I'm having some problems. If I run my web application and I stay on the page, all is loaded properly. However if I go to the web app homepage and while is loading I switch to another browser tab and then I come back, the web app is rendered in a wrong way.

I think the problem comes from jQuery routines. Is there a way to check which routines the app is running without implementing `console.log` everywhere?

Comment: Set some break points in debugger to figure out the scripts but switching tabs during page load should not affect the result

Comment: This behaviour sounds like a rendering bug in the browser, as flipping tabs while the page is loading should have no effect on the page. We cannot help you debug code we cannot see, though. I'd suggest you edit your question to include an example of the problem

Comment: do you experience this on all browsers? some browsers "pause" inactive tabs, but if behaviours are made on timeouts to wait for stuff, the stuff might not be arrived when timeout fires.

Comment: yes, the problem affects all the browser... Its an Angluar4 application